# Delphi and XP embedded

Tags: windows, delphi, embedded

Does anybody know if Delphi (Win32) works with XP embedded

Comment: Do you want to run the Delphi IDE on XP Embedded, or do you mean applications compiled with Delphi?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does, is the short answer

We use Delphi 5 with WePos (windows embedded for point of sale) and it works fine.

Running Interbase 5.5 via the BDE

The only thing we have to do is install an extra file. the file is called "libraryfiles.exe" , not very descriptive I know, here is more info to help you find it

> Ascentive Libary Files
>
> Version: 2.0.0.24
>
> Product name:  Libraryfiles Install Program

Answer (score 3):

In general, it seems to work ([example Delphi program for XPE](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magewf.asp)), but there could be some problems when using some specific libraries (i.e. XML) where XP embedded could differ from an usual XP installation.

Answer (score 1):

I recently finished a project with an ActiveForm, making heavy use of OpenGL and has a ton of third party libraries inside and everything works like a charm on XP embedded.

BTW, I wasn't told that this thing was meant to run on XP embedded...

Answer (score 1):

XP Embedded **is** XP, with the ability to remove lots of stuff. Almost anything that runs on XP can be made to run on XPE. Often the key is finding the libraries as [@Re0sless did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482777/delphi-and-xp-embedded/482933#482933).